# Plot average of multiple numpy arrays with confidence intervals shaded in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, confidence-interval

I have 100s of numpy arrays of size 1x2000 (e.g. `np.array([1, 2, 3, ....]`). I'm trying to plot the average line across all numpy arrays with the corresponding 5th and 95th confidence intervals (CIs), where the CIs are shaded. I've been trying to do this via `matplotlib` and `plotly`, but can't get it to work. How can I do this?

Data is arranged like below:

```
data = 

[0.5, 0.6, 0.9, ...]
[0.17, 0.41, 0.65, ...]
[0.54, 0.29, 0.64, 0.21, ...]
```

Also, if the size of each numpy array is of slightly different length, I'll likely just cut all data to the shortest length to compute the mean (e.g. `data_avg = df['data_values'].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plt.fill_between, we can shade between the 5th and 95th percentiles

```
import random
import numpy as np

def create_arrays():
    arrays = []
    for i in range(10):
        arrays.append(np.random.rand(1, 2000))
    return arrays

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_arrays(arrays):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.plot(np.mean(arrays, axis=0)[0], label='Mean')
    plt.fill_between(range(2000), np.percentile(arrays, 5, axis=0)[0], np.percentile(arrays, 95, axis=0)[0], alpha=0.5, label='5% and 95% confidence interval')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

arrays = create_arrays()
plot_arrays(arrays)
```

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I need to plot the mean across all numpy arrays with the CIs. How would I amend your line `plt.plot(x)
plt.fill_between(range(len(x)), np.percentile(x, 5, axis=0), np.percentile(x, 95, axis=0), alpha=0.5)` to do so?

Comment: @MAsoccer9 Ive changed the answer, so first we plot the mean first and then add fill_between